# Integração entre Alfresco e Liferay, para utilizar o Alfresco como biblioteca de documentos

Tags: alfresco, liferay, ecm, cms

Estou com a necessidade de criar uma interface publica que permita acesso e download de arquivos disponibilizados no Alfresco Share.
Estive tentando fazer isso utilizando a integração existente entre o Alfresco e o Liferay.
Encontrei três formas de integrar o Alfresco e o Liferay

- Adicionando o Alfresco como repositório

  - necessário configurar para que o usuário do liferay seja utilizado na autenticação do alfresco
  - necessário que haja usuários com username e senhas iguais em ambas aplicações
- Configurar o alfresco para utilizar o Alfresco como sistema de arquivos

  - os arquivos são armazenados no alfresco como binários
  - os nomes das pastas são ids
  - não é viável acessar os arquivos via alfresco
- Configurar o alfresco share como portlet do liferay

  - necessário modificar a chain authentication do alfresco
  - permite que vc use 3 novas portlets para integrar o alfresco share ao liferay
  - continua precisando de um usuário autenticado

Ainda não consegui encontrar uma forma que me atendesse, porque em duas dessas formas eu preciso que haja um usuário logado, e na outra os arquivos ficam fisicamente no afresco, mas são salvos lá no formato binário, o que inviabiliza que sejam manipulados por lá.
Talvez algo tenha me passo desapercebido, ou haja uma forma melhor de fazer isso.

Answer (score 2):

**Sobre utilizar o mesmo usuário**

- Crie um web services que trabalhe com um
  usuário e senha padrão;
- Crie seu log de usuários em uma base a parte (Para o Alfresco e o Liferay será sempre o mesmo usuário só que você saberá que não é, e terá esses dados armazenados em outro lugar se    houver a necessidade de utiliza-los mais tarde).

**Referente ao armazenamento**

- Alfresco como repositório